# Correct HQL query?

Tags: java, postgresql, hql

Hello what is wrong on this HQL query?

```
SELECT m
FROM zakazka m
WHERE m.id =
(
    SELECT s.zakazka
    FROM smlouva s
    WHERE s.id =
    (
        SELECT z.ramcova_smlouva_na_jejimz_zaklade_je_zakazka_vytvorena
        FROM zakazka z
        WHERE z.id = 7880
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind the query?  I think we can replace those subqueries with appropriate joins.

Comment: From table zakazka i want find "ramcova_smlouva_na_jejimz_zaklade_je_zakazka_vytvorena", 
which is id of "smlouva", from "smlouva" i want find "zakazka" which is id of single record in table zakazka

Comment: I gave you a join query below which might be better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw SQL query which should achieve the same thing as your nested subquery:

```
SELECT m
FROM zakazka m
INNER JOIN smlouva s
    ON m.id = s.zakazka
INNER JOIN zakazka z
    ON s.id = z.ramcova_smlouva_na_jejimz_zaklade_je_zakazka_vytvorena
WHERE z.id = 7880
```

Comment: its throws error
unexpected token: ON: line 1:46: unexpected token: ON

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing column name on you first SELECT statement (select m."something here")

Do you have any exception available to attach?

Comment: I want whole line, not single column